# DEM for Russia in WGS84

Tags: raster, dem, russia

I'm looking for a DEM of Russia projected in WGS84. Anyone have any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Perhaps this page [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) will be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your region in Russia you can use, for 90m resolution:
https://dwtkns.com/srtm/

From the readme-file:

> The data  distributed here  are in  ARC GRID,  ARC ASCII  and Geotiff format, in
> decimal degrees and datum WGS84.  They are derived from the USGS/NASA SRTM data.
> CIAT  have  processed  this  data  to  provide  seamless  continuous  topography
> surfaces.  Areas with  regions of no  data in the  original SRTM data  have been
> filled using interpolation methods described by Reuter et al. (2007).

As of 2014 the SRTM DEM is released as a 1-arc second global digital elevation model which has a spatial resolution of about 30 meters. That can be downloaded here: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

To use the interface check the guide here: https://gisgeography.com/usgs-earth-explorer-download-free-landsat-imagery/